# Need help getting serial data using Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to use Octave and the [Instrument Control package](http://wiki.octave.org/Instrument_control_package) to read in serial data through the USB port. Right now I'm just sending test data through the port. Zeros and ones.

I'm getting correct data through the USB when I use `screen`:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB1
```

I get strange data when I try to use Octave though. I think I'm doing something wrong. Here's an example. I think I should be getting 0 or 1 from `srl_read`:

```
> pkg load all
> s1 = serial("/dev/ttyUSB1", 9600)
s1 = 3
> srl_read(s1,1)
ans = 49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the ASCII value of "1" from the serial port in this case:

```
octave:1> x = double ("1")
x =  49
```

Answer taken from the help-octave mailing list, where the developer of instrument-control [answered your question](https://mailman.cae.wisc.edu/pipermail/help-octave/2012-October/054745.html) more thoroughly.